# Remove words from file which has two or more of the same letters letters in a row

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have a word list, such as:

```
word
letter
linux
tagggs
```

I want to remove `letter` and `tagggs` from it (because they have two or more of the same letters in a row). Maybe this can be done using sed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use one of the regex tools that supports backreferences e.g.

```
sed '/\(.\)\1/d' file

grep -v '\(.\)\1' file
```

Change `.` to `[[:alpha:]]` if you really want to restrict it to repeated letters rather than any repeated characters.

Comment: that's removing lines, not words. but it works for that input format