# Remove words from dictionary which has two or more letters at any plave in wor

Tags: delete, dictionary, words

Basicaly I have dictionary from which I would like to remove words which contain two or more letters at any place in sentence for ex.

```
bold
leTTer
reMoveMe
quote
lanGuaGe
spaces
```

Output should be like this

```
bold
quote
space
```

Is it possible to do it with seed ?

Comment: You can modify the answer to your previous question [Remove words from file which has two or more of the same letters letters in a row](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/520875/remove-words-from-file-which-has-two-or-more-of-the-same-letters-letters-in-a-ro) to allow zero or more characters in between. BTW `spaces` has 2 `s` characters so should also be removed based on your stated criterion

Comment: All words in the example contain "two or more letters at any place", don't they?

Comment: @DonHolgo yes they do and I want to remove them

Comment: @SlobodanVidovic The words in your desired output still have two or more letters, though.